# " 'undefined' is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

So, I wanted to write code that creates units with random stats.

This is the Enemy Constructor:

```
  function Enemy(name, atk, def, hp, mp, xp_val){
    this.name = name;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def= def;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.max_hp = hp;
    this.mp = mp;
    this.max_mp = mp;
    this.xp_val = xp_val;
    totalEnemies++; 
}
```

This is the supplementary code to create random enemies.

```
function createEnemy(name, difficulty){
    var atk = getIntBetween(5, 10);
    var def = getIntBetween (0, 5);
    var hp = getIntBetween(15, 25);
    var mp = getIntBetween(0, 7);
    var xp_val = getIntBetween(5, 10);
    var multiplier;

    if (difficulty === 1 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "easy"){ multiplier = 1; }
    if (difficulty === 2 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "average"){ multiplier = 2; }
    if (difficulty === 3 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "challenge"){ multiplier = 4; }
    if (difficulty === 4 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "damn"){ multiplier = 7; }
    if (difficulty === 5 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "nightmare"){ multiplier = 11; }

    atk *= multiplier;
    def *=multiplier;
    hp *= multiplier;
    mp *= multiplier;
    xp_val *= multiplier;

    return new Enemy(name, atk, def, hp, mp, xp_val);
}
```

I tried to create an instance with:

```
var goblin_02 = createEnemy("Goblin Dirtbag", 2);
```

and I get the error in the title. This was all in attempt to circumvent JS' lack of overloaded constructors, where did I go wrong?

Comment: could you tell us on which line the error occured?

Comment: Perhaps the getIntBetween function isn't defined?  What happens if you change the last line of the function to this?  

`return [name, atk, def, hp, mp, xp_val];`

Comment: It is, do you think I should add it? It would be nice if I could tell you, it can 'run' fine but I just get a problem once it reaches this part/tries to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it's here:

```
if (difficulty === 1 || difficulty.toLowerCase() === "easy"){ multiplier = 1; }
```

You're passing `2` for `difficulty`. It's not equal to `1`, so you're next essentially calling `2.toLowerCase()`. Unsurprisingly, that's not a real thing.

Comment: There's an if right below the one you're referring to that checks for that.

Comment: Oh!! so the toLowerCase() method acting on a number is causing the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in the code and it's worked.

```
<script>
        var totalEnemies = 0;
        function Enemy(name, atk, def, hp, mp, xp_val){
            this.name = name;
            this.atk = atk;
            this.def= def;
            this.hp = hp;
            this.max_hp = hp;
            this.mp = mp;
            this.max_mp = mp;
            this.xp_val = xp_val;
            totalEnemies++; 
        }
        function createEnemy(name, difficulty){
            var atk = getIntBetween(5, 10);
            var def = getIntBetween (0, 5);
            var hp = getIntBetween(15, 25);
            var mp = getIntBetween(0, 7);
            var xp_val = getIntBetween(5, 10);
            var multiplier;

            if (((typeof(difficulty) === "number") &&  (difficulty === 1)) || ((typeof(difficulty) === "string") &&  (difficulty.toLowerCase() === "easy"))){ multiplier = 1; }
            if (difficulty === 2){ multiplier = 2; }
            if (difficulty === 3){ multiplier = 4; }
            if (difficulty === 4){ multiplier = 7; }
            if (difficulty === 5){ multiplier = 11; }

            atk *= multiplier;
            def *=multiplier;
            hp *= multiplier;
            mp *= multiplier;
            xp_val *= multiplier;

            return new Enemy(name, atk, def, hp, mp, xp_val);
        }
        function create() {
            var goblin_02 = createEnemy("Goblin Dirtbag", 2);
            console.log(goblin_02,totalEnemies);
        }
        function getIntBetween(i,j){
            var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * j) + i);
            return number;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="create()">

</body>
```

You just need to change the if condition for all the if blocks.